# Prove the inequality $|| P(u)-P(v) ||^2 \leq (u-v)^T(P(u)-P(v))$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

So I found this inequality in a paper:

$|| P(u)-P(v) ||^2 \leq (u-v)^T(P(u)-P(v))$ with $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $P$ is a projection and $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm.

But I have no clue how to get this inequality. Thanks for any information or pointers to resources.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe one could use $P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^d\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i$ for an orthonormal basis $e_i$ of the space projected onto?

Comment: Is $P$ a projection to a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Is $P$ nonexpansive ?

Comment: You should add more context. If $P$ is a (linear) orthogonal projection, then $P^T=P^2=P$, which makes this inequality even an equality. But maybe that's not what projection means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $P$ is onto a linear subspace $V$ of $H=\mathbb R^n$. By the Kolmogorov criterion,

$$\langle  P(x)-x, v-P(x) \rangle \geq 0  \ \ \text{ for every } v \in V  $$
where $ \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the usual inner product in $H$.

Since $P(u) $ and $P(v) $ belong in $V$,
$$  \langle P(u)-u,P(v)-P(u) \big \rangle  \geq 0$$ and
$$\langle - P(v)+v, -P(u)+ P(v) \rangle \geq 0.$$
Hence,
$$ \langle  P(u) - P(v), P(v) - P(u)  \big \rangle  + \langle v-u, P(v) - P_C(u)  \big \rangle   \geq 0 .$$
This then implies that
$$||P(u) -P(v)||^2 \leq  \langle v-u,P(v) -P(u) \big \rangle. $$

Edit: The Kolmogorov criterion states that if $P $ is an orthogonal projection onto a closed subspace $V$ of a Hilbert space $H$ and $x \in H$, then
$$P(x)=y \iff y \in V \text{ and  } \langle  y-x, v-y \rangle \geq 0  \ \ \text{ for every } v \in V . $$
For a proof  see Theorem 4.3-1 in  "Linear and nonlinear
Functional Analysis
with Applications" by Philippe G. Ciarlet.

Comment: Nice answer. Can you state the Kolmogorov criterion?

Comment: @user326159 I edited my answer.